# Creating custom node to extend HTMLIFrameElement

Tags: javascript, custom-element

Is it possible to create a custom element like : "" and this new element will have all the functionality of an iframe element? (its own document/window objects and such...) ?

Comment: Any reason why a normal iframe does not suffice?

Comment: @Shilly i would like to add more functionality to a special element i'm creating and i need it to be like an iframe (with document/window objects)

Comment: You could try fiddling around with `document.registerElement()` and cloning the iframe prototype, but I can't guarantee it'll work for everything an iframe provides out of the box. It does sounds like non-trivial work. Care to explain what problem a custom element will solve that a normal iframe can't?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements

Comment: @Shilly I'm getting an error when i'm using HTMLIFrameElement instead of HTMLElement -- "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor: autonomous custom elements must extend HTMLElement"

Comment: Have you tried inheriting from HTMLElement and then using the iframe prototype as I suggested? I've never tried this, so I'm not sure if it's even possible. Hence my question. Why does it *have* to be a custom element instead of just a normal iframe where you add some extra functions?

Comment: @Shilly i didn't quite get how to use the iframe prototype. and regarding your question , i would just like to wrap everything in a nice custom element that's all if it's possible than great and if not that i will just use a normal iframe , but its seems to be possible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Extending `<iframe>`**

To extend a standard HTML element, you must use the `{ extends: "element" }` in the `customElements.define()` method:

```
class MyFrame extends HTMLIFrameElement {
    constructor () {
        super()
        console.log( 'created')
    }
}
customElements.define( 'my-frame', MyFrame, { extends: 'iframe' } )
```

Then use the `is="custom-element"` attribute to create the extended element:

```
<iframe is='my-frame'></iframe>
```

You can then use it as a standard `<iframe>` and add your custom features.

---

**Defining a new HTML tag**

Alternaltey, if you want a new tag name, create an autonomous custom element (derived from `HTMLElement`) with a standard `<iframe>` element inside :

```js
class NewFrame extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    console.log( 'created' ) 
    this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
        .innerHTML = "<iframe></iframe>"
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    setTimeout( () =>
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector( 'iframe' ).contentDocument.body.innerHTML = this.innerHTML
    )
  }
}
customElements.define( 'new-frame', NewFrame )
```

In this example, the custom element will use the content of the `<new-frame>` to populate the `<iframe>` document.

```
<new-frame>Hello world !</new-frame>
```

The drawback of this solution is that your new element won't act as an `<iframe>`. You'll have to define some custom methods for all the feature you want to forward to the `<iframe>` inside.

Comment: Thanks! any chance i can also change the tag name ? or it's not possible?

Comment: @avidahan no, if you want a new tag name, you'll need to create an autonomous custom element, and and add an <iframe> inside it.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: @avidahan I've added an alternate example.